# Defining $e^{S+T}$ as a series

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $S$ and $T$ be matrices, such that $ST = TS$. In a book on differential equations I can read the following:

Binomial theorem: $(S+T)^n=n!\sum\limits_{j+k=n}\frac{S^j T^k}{j!k!}$ $\rbrace$ (1)

$e^{S+T}=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{j+k=n}\frac{S^j T^k}{j!k!}}_{(2)}=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{S^j}{j!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{T^k}{k!}}_{(3)}=e^S e^T$.

How exactly does (2) follow from (1) and (3) follow from (2)?

Comment: This all requires $S$ and $T$ to commute.

Comment: That's definitely not right unless $S$ and $T$ commute. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Matrix_Lie_group_illustration).

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yes, thank you, I've added the commutativity condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $e^{S+T}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}(S+T)^n$. Just plug in $(1)$ for $(S+T)^n$ [which only holds if $ST=TS$, as *Robert Israel* correctly remarks] and cancel $\frac1{n!}\cdot n!$ to obtain $(2)$. The step from $(2)$ to $(3)$ involves rearranging the summands, which is allowed per absolute convergence of the series.